# Making input/form bar responsive using Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a banner going across a page that allows the user to filter the data displayed. This needs to be responsive. However when decreasing the size of the browser window the date picker (jQuery datepicker) buttons go to a different line, and the whole thing looks, frankly, horrific. The submit button goes ove the top of things too. I have experimented with media queries but, to be honest, I am not hugely familiar with Bootstrap responsive layouts. This is an existing project that I am extending, so any advice hugely appreciated. There are 2 external controls used: jQuery datepicker and Sumo Select. Markup below:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 no-gutter">
      <div class="form-inline inline-fields  ">
        <h3>From</h3>
        <input class="form-control dateField datepicker" id="dateRangeFrom" name="dateRangeFrom" type="text" value="" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"><button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger btn btnCalendar"><span class="calendarIcon"></span></button>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 no-gutter">
      <div class="form-inline inline-fields  ">
        <h3>To</h3>
        <input class="form-control dateField datepicker" id="dateRangeTo" name="dateRangeTo" type="text" value="" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"><button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger btn btnCalendar"><span class="calendarIcon"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 no-gutter">
      <div class="left form-inline">
        <h3>Status</h3>
        <div class="SumoSelect" tabindex="0">
          <select class="sumo-select form-control" id="SelectOptions" multiple="multiple" name="SelectOptions">
                            <option value="0">Option 0</option>
                            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                        </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 no-gutter">
      <div class="form-inline  ">
        <h3>Search</h3> <input class="form-control search" id="SearchText" name="SearchText" type="text" value="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 no-gutter">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="primary">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is CSS to make the h3 tags display inline with the form fields. This goes awry too when the browser viewport is resized.

Comment: Can you provide the jQuery and css too?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```css
  .datepicker{display: inline-block; width: 94%;}
```

```html
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .datepicker{display: inline-block; width: 94%;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-3 col-sm-6 no-gutter">
          <div class="form-inline inline-fields">
            <h3>From</h3>
            <input class="form-control dateField datepicker" id="dateRangeFrom" name="dateRangeFrom" type="text" value="" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"><button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger btn btnCalendar"><span class="calendarIcon"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 no-gutter">
          <div class="form-inline inline-fields  ">
            <h3>To</h3>
            <input class="form-control dateField datepicker" id="dateRangeTo" name="dateRangeTo" type="text" value="" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"><button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger btn btnCalendar"><span class="calendarIcon"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 no-gutter">
          <div class="left form-inline">
            <h3>Status</h3>
            <div class="SumoSelect" tabindex="0">
              <select class="sumo-select form-control" id="SelectOptions" multiple="multiple" name="SelectOptions">
                <option value="0">Option 0</option>
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="3">Option 3</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 no-gutter">
          <div class="form-inline  ">
            <h3>Search</h3>
            <input class="form-control search" id="SearchText" name="SearchText" type="text" value="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12 no-gutter text-center">
          <div class="form-inline  ">
            <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="primary">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```